# Why did a run-time error occur instead of a compile error?

Tags: c#, variables, compilation, runtime-error

My question is in the comments in the code below:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int div1 = 5/a;  // a isn't Unknown until Runtime, 
                         // if a==0, Runtime error occurred. it's Ok!

        a = 0;
        int div2 = 10/a; // local variable a's Value is zero 
                         // and not exist any sentence 
                         // between "a=0;" and "int div2=10/a;" to change variable a, 
                         // why did a runtime error occur instead of a compile error?
    }
```

Thank you in advance for your answer.
I apologize for poor English writing because English is my second language.

Comment: It's still a runtime error. Compile errors will only occur for known type issues or syntax errors.

Comment: It wouldn't make much sense to let the compiler check if there could be divzero issues at compile time - compiler logic would be much more complicated to just compile your code, imagine if you would pause the code between a=0 and 10/a to change the value of a from another thread. the compiler would have to check this as well

Comment: Compiler doesn't try to run the code and see what happens. So it doesn't keep in mind that a==0 when dividing by it, even if a was assigned just one line above. What if a was the result of a complicated computation ? What would be the limit between what it should keep track of and what it shouldn't ?

Comment: C# compiler is not a static analysis tool which analyses your source code to find the potential bugs in your code. It just converts what you write in C# to MSIL.

Comment: There is a limit to how deeply the C# compiler will analyze your code to find mistakes.  That's a pretty low limit for interaction between separate statements in your code, the only non-trivial analysis it does is the one required to implement the definite-assignment rule in the C# Language Specification.  Which is fairly easy to implement, tracking assigned values gets to be a lot more hairy and a lot more error-prone.  Simply put, the language spec doesn't say that this code is illegal so the compiler doesn't burn the cycles to check.  Otherwise easy to diagnose at runtime of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause only in run time variable `a` will be assigned value `0` and so the division will fail with `DivideByZero` exception.

Try doing this `int div2 = 10 / 0;` and will see compiler throw a red squiggly error on spot.

It will also be the same case if you declare `int a` as `constant` like below

```
constant int a = 0;
int div2 = 10 / a;
```

That's because, at compile time; compiler will just substitute the constant value wherever it has been referenced which is same as directly dividing it by `0`. So the line below

```
int div2 = 10 / a;
```

Will become

```
int div2 = 10 / 0;
```

Comment: Additionally, you get the same compile error when dividing by a constant which is `0`.

Comment: @Rob, that true cause compiler will do the substitution at compile time. See edited answer.

Comment: thanks Rahul, you've defined constant but my question was something else. please read question again.

Comment: Yes I have red it and the answer is: at compile time compiler don't know (OR) have no way of checking wither what value the variable `int a` holds and so it won't complain at all. Only at run time the value will be assigned. hope it clear now.

Comment: @programmer1, consider accepting the answer if it's helpful.